# Monitor third party services using NewRelic

Tags: monitoring, newrelic

We are using NewRelic to monitor our application along with some third party services as like nginx, logstash, etc. Is there any way through which we can monitor those 3rd party services ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some third party services can be monitored through the use of third party [plugins](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugins/plugins-new-relic/installing-plugins/installing-plugin). If the service that you're looking to monitor isn't available within an existing plugin, you can either [develop your own plugin](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugins/developing-plugins) or use the Agent SDK to instrument your service manually.